# Can't access a remote resource from an extension on firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have been trying to make a request to my own server A from an extension running on a page B. Everything is working smoothly if I'm running the extension on Chrome but it fails on Firefox with this error:

```
'Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at A (“connect-src”).'
```

The extension adds a button to the B page and tries to make a PUT request to server A using fetch with this code

```
function sendData(body) {
    fetch(`${API_URL}/request-help`, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
    })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        })
}
```

I've added to the manifest
`"host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],`

Tried adding CSP

```
  "content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'self' "
  }
```

Comment: Make the request in your background script as shown [here](/a/55292071).

Comment: According to the link, it seems that if this were the problem, it shouldn't work on chrome.

Comment: Only if the server responds with identical Access-Control headers for both browsers.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The server returns the same response for both of the browser, I don't see why they should differ.

Comment: Since I don't see the headers and where exactly you make the request I can only guess. If it's a content script and it works in Chrome then the URL must be either same-origin or the response has the correct Access-Control headers. If everything's the same (i.e. no redirects, no differences in the page's CSP and in the API's headers) and it doesn't work in Firefox then it's a bug in Firefox.

Comment: If this is an extension:// script (like an action page, a background script), then it's probably the way Firefox implements ManifestV3 - it denies host permissions by default and requires you to manually request it via browser.permissions API.

Comment: I've followed your advice and moved fetch calls to background service and now it seems to be working. Wanted to avoid doing this, but it actually is pretty good from architecture's point of view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've followed @xOxxOm advice and moved the fetch calls to a background service and now everything seems to be working. Wanted to avoid doing this, but I actually like it from code's architecture's point of view.